# Lost DB SCHEMA after NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints

After execute instructions (for all DB tables)

```
ALTER TABLE myTableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE myTableName CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

I loss all relations SCHEMA(s) :-(

DB constraints still valid but i can't  find anymore schemas with SQL Server Management Studio!

https://goo.gl/photos/9TA7fZF37ucKNnTb9

Comment: did you try this too?    ALTER TABLE myTableName WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

Comment: note : betweene the two istructions i delete the content of all tables

Comment: and what exactly do you want to Do?

Comment: i want to delete the content of all tables that have relation constraints (foreign keys)

Answer (score 0):

offfff
i found the solution
the problem doesn't in "CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL" or "NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"
the problem is when i delete all tables (with vb program) the sysdiagrams
table is deleted too, so i can't find the relation schemas.
i'm sorry